# wget -c --content-disposition results in 403 forbidden

Tags: wget, ceph

Downloading a file from ceph object store using presigned url results in 403 error when options `-c` and `--content-disposiiton` are used.

Debug output shows it requests a **HEAD** which is why it *fails*, but if the options are used by themselves it only requests **GET** and *succeeds*. So why does it request a **HEAD** of the object, and can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> why does it request a HEAD

In order to get value of [`Content-Disposition` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) from [`wget` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget)

> `--content-disposition`
>
> If this is set to on, experimental (not fully-functional) support for "Content-Disposition" headers is
> enabled. This can currently result in extra round-trips to the server
> for a "HEAD" request, and is known to suffer from a few bugs, which is
> why it is not currently enabled by default.

> can I fix it

Yes if you can specify that you want access to `GET` and `HEAD` whilst procuring *presigned url*. I never used `ceph`, so only thing I can suggest is for looking for such featured in furnished documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately presigned URLs only allow GET. I've tried other combinations of options and including them in .wgetrc but whenever those two options are selected it requests a HEAD and the download fails. But previously (July 2022) it worked.